# grep/awk array from line where text maches

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to make a shell script that searches some lines in .log file.
I need to first search the number and place them into a file, then search in that file for each ID and store them in array in order to search again in file for the responses.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
logFile='/path/to/file.log'
if [[ $1 = "" ]]; then
        echo "Use ./analize.sh <number>";
        exit 0
fi
result=rs-$1.log;
touch result;
grep -B 7 -A 1 $1 $logFile >> result;
IDarr[i]=($(cat result | grep 'ID:'))
while [ -n "$IDarr[i]" ]
        do grep -B 2 -A 6 ${IDarr[n]} $result >> idmatched.log
done
exit 0
```

Thanks

logfile example:

```
017-06-13 12:00:32 - Outbount Request
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
ID: 132
Request: [FW1;14dwa90266681;12eqw28631898;99514;321;634579;224943746;2]
Encription: YES
Export-Value: 2048
Type: String
Content: {Status=[Failed], Target={"number":"9892213994","asID":"a321kpok41hadw-0-391-12391421.00","version":"09e2da8d-7379-39d9-9c52-be4aba0d49d1", t-qgs-ms=[4], java 1.7, h-ucc-dn=[***************************]}, accept-encoding=[identity], Content-Length=[300],}
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

2017-06-13 12:10:51 - Inbound Response
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
ID: 132
Response-Code: 200
Encription: YES
Export-Value: 2048
Headers: {Content-Length=[39], charset=UTF-8], Date=[13 Jun 2017 12:10:51 GMT]}
Load: {"result":"E9W2KE3MNA","Message":"Successful"}
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

Comment: So... according to this script when $1 is found on a line in your log file, this will bring the 7 lines (-B)efore and 1 line (-A)fter into your `result` file. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Yes, and then from IDarr I'm trying to make an array with lines that contains "ID:" in order to search them again in log file and print the -B2 -A6 when it finds the unique ID: xxxxx

Comment: It's hard to think through this without an example file, but I think just: `grep -B 7 -A 1 $1 $logFile | grep 'ID:' | grep  -B 2 -A 6 -f - $logfile >> idmatched.log` would work. That `-f -` tells the last `grep` to use stdin as the search term.

Comment: I have edited to add a log file example.

Comment: I ran a test with that grep one-liner I posted above and it did the trick. Just swap out all of your code after `touch result` with that `grep -B 7 -A 1 $1 $logFile | grep 'ID:' | grep -B 2 -A 6 -f - $logfile >> idmatched.log` and you should be golden.